# IIS issue with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, windows-7

I am trying to get my project to use my IIS virtual directory, here is how I have it setup..

In Windows 7..

My project has a Web Application, which is located in my Projects folder..
In IIS, I created a new Virtual Directory pointing to my Web Application,
gave IIS permissions..

can access it fine using http://localhost/WebApplication

Now in Visual Studio 2010, I goto properties of the WebApplication, select "Use Local IIS Web server", type in "http://localhost/WebApplication", sits there for a few mins then a popup error..

---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
To access local IIS Web sites, you must install the following IIS components:


In addition, you must run Visual Studio in the context of an administrator account.

For more information, press F1.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Does not list any components missing..
Any ideas? Rather not have my project in inetpub/wwwroot

Comment: **In addition, you must run Visual Studio in the context of an administrator account.**

Comment: I am running as admin, even says in title bar.. eventually gave up, unless someone knows how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Try running Visual Studio as administrator.

Right click your Visual Studio shortcut and click "Run as Administrator".